# ssh-keyscan - Is there any way to specify a port other than 22 from within the file specified by -f?

Tags: ssh, ansible, rsa

I am looking for a way using ssh-keyscan to possibly define a port within the keyscan file specified with the -f flag instead of having to specify it on the command line.

The following is how I currently do it:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keyscan -f /home/ansible/.ssh/test-scanner-keyscan_hosts -p 16005 >> /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts;
```

Contents of the keyscan file:

```
mainserver1.org,shortname1,shortname2
mainserver2.org,shortname1,shortname2
```

The issue is, each "mainserver" has a unique ssh port that is different from the others.  While this will cause mainserver1 to work, since it's port is 16005, mainserver2 will fail because it's port is 17005.  The only way around it currently is to try to do each ssh-keyscan command separately and specifying each different port such that it works.

Instead, I want to be able to specify them within the file, and/or utilize a method that allows for a scanning of a list allowing for unique ports.  The issue is, there doesn't seem to be any way to do that.

I tried the following within the keyscan file, and it does not work:

```
mainserver1.org:16005,shortname1,shortname2
mainserver2.org:17005,shortname1,shortname2
```

Is there any way to make this work, or any way other than ssh-keyscan, or some other way within ansible to make this function like I hope it does?  Otherwise, I have to do an ssh-keyscan task for EVERY server because the ssh ports are all different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the future, you will want to include your attempt and the error it is producing for you, since this is a **programming** stack exchange; please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: I will do that, and also edit this if I can soon to showcase the actual issue as well.  I will try to implement your solution and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually welcome to use that format, and then use it to drive the actual implementation since [`ssh-keyscan -f` accepts "-" to read from stdin](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/ssh-keyscan.1.html#description); thus:

```bash
scan_em() {
  local fn
  local port
  fn="$1"
  for port in $(grep -Eo ':[0-9]+' $fn | sed s/:// | sort | uniq); do
    sed -ne "s/:${port}//p" $fn | ssh-keyscan -f - -p $port
  done
}
scan_em /home/ansible/.ssh/test-scanner-keyscan_hosts >> /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: This appears to be the answer I was looking for, though when I sourced the script, despite the redirection attempt of output to the known_hosts file internal to it, it outputted only to stdout.  When I made it executable and ran it, I needed to do the redirection in the command itself.  It's fine, it still seemed to work, thanks!